# How to send embedded Facebook video URL on discord text channel

Tags: python, discord.py

Since discord no longer support embedded Facebook URL in text channel, I wanted to created a bot that will send an embedded video to the text channel when it detect user sending a Facebook video URL.

**What I've done:**
I get the video source by the user input's Facebook link. After getting the video source, i proceed to send the video source URL to discord channel to embedded the video.

```
import discord
import sys
import re
import requests as r

ERASE_LINE = '\x1b[2K'


token = 'xxx'

client = discord.Client()



@client.event
async def on_message(message):


    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith("https://www.facebook.com/"):
             userInput = message.content

             try:
                 LINK = userInput
                 html = r.get(LINK)
                 hdvideo_url = re.search('hd_src:"(.+?)"', html.text)[1]
             except r.ConnectionError as e:
                 print("OOPS!! Connection Error.")
             except r.Timeout as e:
                 print("OOPS!! Timeout Error")
             except r.RequestException as e:
                 print("OOPS!! General Error or Invalid URL")
             except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
                 print("Ok ok, quitting")
                 sys.exit(1)
             except TypeError:
                 print("Video May Private or Hd version not avilable")
             else:
                 hd_url = hdvideo_url.replace('hd_src:"', '')
                 print("\n")
                 print("High Quality: " + hd_url)
                 await message.channel.send(hd_url)

    else:
        pass


client.run(token)
```

**Working Example:**

```
https://video.fpen1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t42.27313-2/240922420_2970039856603575_3594354671958668123_n.mp4?_nc_cat=104&vs=4dc6b09030588fa8&_nc_vs=HBksFQAYJEdEUXZYQTYzSVo5S1BJMEtBRnV6M01xSHR1RXhickZxQUFBRhUAAsgBABUAGCRHTWpJV1E0c1QwRjJRVlVDQUthWTB0OE9wWTkxYnJGcUFBQUYVAgLIAQBLBogScHJvZ3Jlc3NpdmVfcmVjaXBlATEgbWVhc3VyZV9vcmlnaW5hbF9yZXNvbHV0aW9uX3NzaW0AKGNvbXB1dGVfc3NpbV9vbmx5X2F0X29yaWdpbmFsX3Jlc29sdXRpb24AEWRpc2FibGVfcG9zdF9wdnFzAA1zdWJzYW1wbGVfZnBzABB2bWFmX2VuYWJsZV9uc3ViABUAJQAcAAAmhISm5O6qwwEVkE4oAkMzGAt2dHNfcHJldmlldxwXQDGkm6XjU%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%3D&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=b16ca8&efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6Im9lcF9oZCIsInNvdXJjZV9zZWdtZW50X2hhbmRsZSI6bnVsbH0%3D&_nc_ohc=67UM9G3a0CAAX-l48P3&_nc_ht=video.fpen1-1.fna&oh=e9b32312bef794b54db3bd186a0a084e&oe=612E3EA5&_nc_rid=c1379fc1a9e14b1&_nc_vts_prog=1&vts=1&_nc_vts_internal=1
```

[image]

Problem: It doesn't work for some video even its public. For example: it showed me `Video May Private or Hd version not available` even when I input a public video. [facebook vid](https://www.facebook.com/100013621321970/videos/1547757982242385)

[image]

**So my question:** Is it possible to achieved my intention by just sending the video source link ? And why some video couldn't work even its set as public.

Comment: it seems like it's doing exactly what you asked it to do: try to `hdvideo_url = re.search('hd_src:"(.+?)"', html.text)[1]`. `re.search` didn't find `hd_src` in the response HTML, therefore returned `None`, then exception block caught the `TypeError`.  

so all HTML responses without `hd_src` will return `TypeError`, private or public.